# DynamoDB client with auto refresh credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm creating DynamoDB client using IAM credentials obtained via STS assume role.

```
@Provides
public DynamoDbEnhancedClient DdbClientProvider() {

final AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder stsClientBuilder = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
        .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration());

final AssumeRoleRequest assumeRoleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest().withRoleSessionName("some.session.name");

assumeRoleRequest.setRoleArn("arnRole");

final AssumeRoleResult assumeRoleResult = stsClientBuilder.build().assumeRole(assumeRoleRequest);


final Credentials creds = assumeRoleResult.getCredentials();
final AwsSessionCredentials sessionCredentials = AwsSessionCredentials.create(creds.getAccessKeyId()
        , creds.getSecretAccessKey(), creds.getSessionToken());
final AwsCredentialsProviderChain credsProvider = AwsCredentialsProviderChain.builder()
        .credentialsProviders(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(sessionCredentials))
        .build();

final DynamoDbClient ddbClient = DynamoDbClient.builder().region(Region.US_EAST_1)
        .credentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
final DynamoDbEnhancedClient ddbEnhancedclient =
        DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder().dynamoDbClient(ddbClient).build();

return ddbEnhancedClient;
}
```

The main lambda handler looks like below:

```
public void LambdaMainHandler {

DynamoDbEnhancedClient ddbClient;

@Inject
public LambdaMainHandler(final DynamoDbEnhancedClient client) {
    this.ddbClient = client;
}

public LambdaResponse processRequest(final LambdaRequest request) {
    QueryResponse queryResponse = client.query("...")
    return LambdaResponse.builder().setContent(queryResponse.getByteBuffer()).build();
}

}
```

I'm using the DDB client in LambdaMain constructor.

Since this is running in Lambda behind APIGateway, how do I make sure the credentials are refreshed when they expire while executing LambdaMain handler?

Comment: Is your Dynamo in a different account than your Lambda? If it isnt, then you dont need to do this. You simply set up an IAM role for your lambda that gives it permission to access the dynamo table it needs access to. Only that lambda can assume the role - no users, no other resources - and it only gives access to that dynamo -- 

Since you said however you are using STS i am going to assume that its in another account... in which case ...again, you dont need a TTL on the credentials - you simply create a role that onyl has access to this table, and ONLY can be assumed by the lambda

Comment: if you are worried that your lambda is going to try to act when the AssumeRole action has not been accesssed for some time, then you jsut need to check if DynamoDB client is None/Null or has thrown an exception - when attempting to create the DynamoDb client session, if the role that is being provided is not valid then it will either return None/Null (depending on a few circumstances) or it will toss an exception (may vary somewhat depending on language of SDK used)

Comment: Yes, the dynamoDB table is in different account (let's call it Account B) than lambda (let's call it Account A). I created a role DynamoDB-Access-Role in account B which has access to DynamoDB, and in account A, I'm doing above logic `assumeRoleRequest.setRoleArn("DynamoDB-Access-Role");` and then use these credentials to create a DynamoDB client in account A. Can you give me an example what you mean by your last statement - `you simply create a role that onyl has access to this table, and ONLY can be assumed by the lambda`

Comment: see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_lambda-access-dynamodb.html as an example policy. When doing it cross account, the difference is that you need to add a Principle key to the permissions and assign that to the lambda arn. You should also look into IAM Trust https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/

Comment: IAM trust link provides sts:AssumeRole solution. I'm still unclear what do you mean by adding Principle Key to permissions?